# Is it possible to place Rails controller files in app/controllers sub directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3 and I'd like to move some controller files from `app/controllers` to `app/controllers/a-subdirectory`. I don't want to namespace those controllers and they don't correspond to nested resources. It is only to have a more organized file structure.

When I try to `articles_controller` to `app/controllers/a-subdirectory` and call a related routing path helper I get the error `ActionController::RoutingError: uninitialized constant ArticlesController`.

It there a way to tell Rails to look up the controller files recursively in `app/controllers`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally could do by simply adding `app/controllers/a-subdirectory` to the `autoload_paths`:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/controllers/a-subdirectory
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:path` option for that,

```
resources :posts, :path => "/my-dir/posts"
```

Check out [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing) for more information.

Comment: Does not work for me, it creates paths like `/my-dir/posts` while I want to keep paths like `/posts`.